# Clearing mouseclicks buffer in openGL

Tags: opengl, glut

I need to clear any mouse clicks which has happened before the end of an animation.Only mouse clicks afterwards have to be considered.
I tried enabling my mouse function after the animation,but any clicks that happened during the animation was considered.
To my understanding there is a buffer where mouseclicks are stored and during any mouse callback , it takes the co-ordinates and any other info of the first click stored in that buffer.so i need to know how to clear this.
I used fflush(stdin) but it doesnt clear keyboard or the mouse buffer.
Am using windowsxp and programming in visualsudio2008 in c language.i also use glut.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i also use glut.h

Then you can't. If you're doing an animation, it's up to *you* to process (or choose not to process) any messages.

You should not be animating something by looping *within* your display method. Instead, you should set up a timer callback or something that will call `glutPostRedisplay` that will constantly call your drawing method. During this time, you should ignore any messages if you don't want to process them.

Comment: :Thank you.I know i should have called glutPostRedisplay.But i don't want to redesign my program now.All i need is to clear input buffers whenever i want to ,which in turn will make my program bug free.

Comment: @user1391868: It's good to want things. That doesn't make them *possible*, but you can *want* them ;)

Comment: :yes:) made sure my other programs don't have that flaw in design.though i wonder why such a feature is not possible